# Arrow hit number game. Arrow does not hit defined number

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am working on a simple game in assembly language on 8086 assembler, Windows 10. The program takes input from user. The arrow appears at the input number, instead of going to that number horizontally, it goes down. I want the arrow to hit that number. I found [this](https://github.com/Rezve/8086-Microprocessor-Game-in-Assembly-Language) game but I cannot understand it. Please guide me where I am wrong. If possible, please provide detailed explanation.

[image: Screenshot]

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
str db "Enter number to hit: $"
arrow db "--->>$"
my db 0
.code
main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    sub cx, cx

    mov cl, 9
    mov al, '1'
    mov dh, 1
    l1:
        mov ah, 02
        mov dl, 79
        mov dh, dh
        mov bx, 0
        int 10h

        mov ah, 02
        mov dl, al
        int 21h

        inc dh
        inc al
    loop l1

    mov ah, 02
    mov dl, 0
    mov dh, 0
    mov bx, 0
    int 10h

    lea dx, str
    mov ah, 09
    int 21h

    mov ah, 01
    int 21h
    mov my, al

    mov bp, 0
    l2:
        mov ah, 02
        mov dl, bp
        mov dh, my
        mov bx, 0
        int 10h

        mov ah, 02
        mov dl, ' '
        int 21h

        lea dx, arrow
        mov ah, 09
        int 21h

        inc bp
    loop l2

    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
    main endp
end main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> mov ah, 01
> int 21h
> mov my, al
> ```

This input gives you a **character**, so "1" to "9".
Your code needs to work with the number that it represents, that's 1 to 9.
You need to subtract 48 to do this:

```
mov ah, 01
int 21h
sub al, '0'    ; This subtracts 48
mov my, al
```

---

> ```
> mov bp, 0
> l2:
> ...
> loop l2
> ```

This loop cannot work correctly because you forgot to initialize the `CX` register.
Knowing the length of the arrow and the width of the screen, setting `CX=74` will work:

```
    mov bp, 0
    mov cx, 74
l2:
    ...
    loop l2
```

---

> ```
> mov dl, bp    ????????
> mov dh, my
> ```

Your assembler will not accept the `mov dl, bp` instruction! You can't move a 16-bit register into an 8-bit register.
What you can write here is:

```
mov dx, bp  ; 16-bit into 16-bit
mov dh, my  ; 8-bit into 8-bit
```